# How do I handle very large time steps in an LSTM network in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am trying to build a machine learning model which predicts a single number from a series of numbers. I am using an LSTM model with Tensorflow.

You can imagine my dataset to look something like this:

| Index | x data | y data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | `np.ndarray(shape (1000000,) )` | `numpy.float32` |
| 1 | `np.ndarray(shape (1000000,) )` | `numpy.float32` |
| 2 | `np.ndarray(shape (1000000,) )` | `numpy.float32` |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 56 | `np.ndarray(shape (1000000,) )` | `numpy.float32` |

From my x data I created a numpy array `x_train` which I want to use to train the network.
Because I am using an LSTM network, x_train should be of shape *(samples, time_steps, features)*.

In my case I have 57 samples and the length of every sample is 1000000, as you can see in the table above.
Therefore I reshape my x_train array to be shaped like this: (57, 1000000, 1), because I have 57 samples, which each are of length 1000000 and contain a single number.

My model summary looks like this:
[image: model summary]

I tried training the network with the GPU and also with the CPU.
When I tried to train the model using `model.fit()` with the GPU it yields this error:

```py
InternalError: Graph execution error:

Failed to call ThenRnnForward with model config: [rnn_mode, rnn_input_mode, rnn_direction_mode]: 2, 0, 0 , [num_layers, input_size, num_units, dir_count, max_seq_length, batch_size, cell_num_units]: [1, 1, 32, 1, 1000000, 32, 32] 
     [[{{node CudnnRNN}}]]
     [[sequential/lstm/PartitionedCall]] [Op:__inference_train_function_12829]
```

When training with the CPU, it eventually times out (I am using a Jupyter Notebook environment). So it does start, but does not make any progress.

**Question:**
How do I handle very large time steps in an LSTM network in Tensorflow?
I have had a look on other LSTM models and noticed that most of them have a time step size of around 1000-2000. In my case I have 1000000 time steps per sample.
How do I handle this amount of data?
I tried decreasing the batch size but this had no effect. I already use very powerful hardware but I guess my approach is just not that smart.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks! :)

Comment: You can consider downsampling your sequences.

Comment: That's what I'm trying now. Do you think I can compensate the data loss because of downsampling with better training?

Comment: You do not need to "lose" the data.. you can also use it during training.. you will just have shorter sequences and that **might** impact performance.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will try using the downsampled data. Training actually does start now. But I still have a general problem with my model as it seems.

Comment: 1M dimensional features with only 57 samples does not make sense, as you do not have most timesteps defined (since there are only 57 samples).

Comment: I asked a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73457069/why-does-my-lstm-model-predict-wrong-values-although-the-loss-is-decreasing . I followed @AloneTogether tip to downsample the data, but ran into another problem. Maybe you can have a look!